# How separate daytime and mike it as table in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have list of Timestamp and I want to plot as Dumbbell Plot that requires a table which contains four columns as year , month , start day and end day .
my list :
[image]

How to do this list as below ?

[image]

Comment: Looking at your data I guess that you want to use the first day of a series of subsequent as start day and the end as end day? Example: (2017-08-08, 2017-08-09, 2017-08-10) become (year: 2017, month:8, startDay:8, endDay:10).
This is potentially dangerous as no series can extend across months.

Comment: please provide sample data as text, not image. ideally, wrap it in a [mre] that shows what you try that doesn't work.

Comment: sorry I clarified my question know

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comment, I assume your problem to be the following:

You have a time series which includes consecutive dates, e.g.:

```
2017-08-07 
2017-08-08
2017-08-09
2019-05-03
2019-05-04
2020-03-01
2020-03-02
```

You wish to group this by consecutive days so that your data becomes:

```
start        end
2017-08-07   2017-08-09
2019-05-03   2019-05-04
2020-03-01   2020-03-02
```

Fundamentally, to achieve this you need [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html). But first, you need to create a column by which to group. Let's call it `group` for simplicity. As you want to group all consecutive dates together, all consecutive dates must have the same value in the column.

You can achieve this by using

`d['group'] = d.timestamp.diff().gt(pd.Timedelta('1d')).cumsum()`

Let's go through this one step at a time:

- `d['group']` creates a new column 'group' on the data frame 'd'
- `d.timestamp.diff()` computes the difference (in `pd.Timedelta`) between to consequent dates.
- `.gt(pd.Timedelta('1d'))` takes this time difference and checks if its greater than 1 day. It returns true or false. At this point, `d['group']` would contain booleans which are true, whenever a date does not follow onto the one before:

```
2017-08-07   False
2017-08-08   False
2017-08-09   False
2019-05-03   True
2019-05-04   False
2020-03-01   True
2020-03-02   False
```

- Finally, [`.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) returns a cumulative sum over the booleans. It puts in every row the sum of the rows above and itself. As `False` converts to `0` and `True` converts to `1`, every row with `True` increases the sum by 1. And as every block of dates starts with a `True`, every block will get a number larger than the one before.

```
2017-08-07   False   0
2017-08-08   False   0
2017-08-09   False   0
2019-05-03   True    1
2019-05-04   False   1
2020-03-01   True    2
2020-03-02   False   2
```

We can use this ID for the `groupby()`:

```
d.groupby('group')['timestamp'].agg(['min','max'])
```

Here `.agg(['min','max'])` will return two columns with the smallest and greatest timestamp for one group respectively. This will give you your start and end date.

Note that you do not need to split the dates into year, month, and date. Pandas can compute the difference between two timestamps. This also has the advantage, that consecutive dates across month breaks are still recognised as consecutive.

Yet, if you want to create separate columns, you can do so by

```
d['year'] = d.timestamp.dt.year
d['month'] = d.timestamp.dt.month
d['day'] = d.timestamp.dt.day
```

---

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame()
d['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2017-08-07','2017-08-08','2017-08-09','2019-05-03','2019-05-04','2020-03-01','2020-03-02']))
d['group'] = d.timestamp.diff().gt(pd.Timedelta('1d')).cumsum()
d.groupby('group')['timestamp'].agg(['min','max'])
```